# I get different types of fingerprints for ssh on 2 different computers

Tags: ssh, fingerprint

I have two computers that I would like to use to connect via ssh to a remote server. On the second computer I am connecting for the first time.

I get the known fingerprints from the first one using `ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/known_hosts`

But the second computer shows a fingerprint that is not there. It displays an ED25519 fingerprint when using `ssh`

I tried connecting via ssh on a third computer, which ends up showing an ECDSA fingerprint after using `ssh`, which is present in known_hosts of the first computer.

Why are two computers reporting different kinds of fingerprints? How do I verify that the ED25519 fingerprint is the same server the first computer is connecting to?

- first: `OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.2, OpenSSL 1.1.1f 31  Mar 2020`
- second: `OpenSSH_8.5p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1j  16 Feb 2021`
- third: `OpenSSH_8.4p1 Ubuntu-5ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.1.1j  16 Feb 2021`

Comment: different clients with different support of algorithms? Maybe for each client you could provide `ssh -V`?

Comment: added it to the text

Comment: the server doesn't even have a .pub file for whatever reason. for id_rsa I just get "... is not a key file"

Comment: host keys are in /etc/ssh/*.pub

Comment: thanks! `find /etc/ssh -name "*.pub" -exec ssh-keygen -l -f {} \;` lists ECDSA, ED25519, RSA and DSA fingerprints. It's there

Comment: If you want to post that as an answer I'll mark it as solution

Comment: Can't now. If nobody gives an answer also about why you get different key fingerprints in answers in the next few days I will (anybody feel free).